Debezium automatic topic creation not working as expected
I'm working with CDC using a debezium connector managed by Confluent.
I was trying to use the topics creation group feature offered by debezium, to create topics automatically based on the size of each table.
This is my config:
{
    "name": "sample_connector_name",
    "topic.prefix": "sample_connector_prefix",
    "database.dbname": "servicedb",
    "snapshot.mode": "schema_only",
    "snapshot.locking.mode": "none",
    "signal.enabled.channels": "source",
    "signal.data.collection": "servicedb.debezium_signal",
    "incremental.snapshot.allow.schema.changes": "true",
    "incremental.snapshot.chunk.size": 1024,
    "tombstones.on.delete": "true",
    "database.ssl.mode": "preferred",
    "poll.interval.ms": "1000",
    "max.batch.size": "1000",
    "output.data.format": "AVRO",
    "topic.creation.enable": "true",
    "topic.creation.default.partitions": 1,
    "topic.creation.default.replication.factor": -1,
    "topic.creation.groups": "small,medium",
    "topic.creation.small.retention.ms": 432000000,
    "topic.creation.small.include": "sample_connector_prefix.servicedb.users",
    "topic.creation.medium.retention.ms": 86400000,
    "topic.creation.medium.include": "sample_connector_prefix.servicedb.orders,sample_connector_prefix.servicedb.cities",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "status": "RUNNING"
}

I was expecting that Debezium creates the following topics:

For the group small, a topic sample_connector_prefix.servicedb.users with a retention time of 432000000 ms. (5 days)
For the group medium, the topics ample_connector_prefix.servicedb.orders and sample_connector_prefix.servicedb.cities with a retention time of 86400000 ms (1 day)
The rest of the topics for the remaining tables with a default retention time, which is 7 days (this value is the default one in my cluster)

But Debezium is ignoring all the topics under the small and medium groups, and it's just creating the topics that are not listed in those groups.
Do you have any hints about the potential problem?
